# Base class accessing super class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm using python 3.6.
My goal is to make a base class that would be able to somehow access through polymorphism - one of the child class variables.
I know it sounds somewhat 'not oop', so if what im describing can't be done with python - I would like to know what is the best practice for this case.

Following wikipedia's example:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):    # Constructor of the class
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):              # Abstract method, defined by convention only
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclass must implement abstract method")

class Cat(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        return 'Meow!'

class Dog(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        return 'Woof! Woof!'

animals = [Cat('Missy'),
           Cat('Mr. Mistoffelees'),
           Dog('Lassie')]

for animal in animals:
    print animal.name + ': ' + animal.talk()
```

Prints the following:

```
Missy: Meow!
Mr. Mistoffelees: Meow!
Lassie: Woof! Woof!
```

I would like to achieve the exactly same output - using
variable overloading (is that a thing?) instead of method overloading.
The reason is that in the programm im working on - `dog`, `cat`, and every other kind of `animal` will `talk` exactly the same way - influenced only by the data member, such as:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):    # Constructor of the class
        self.name = name
        self.vocabulary = []     # so called abstract data member
    def talk(self):              # Non Abstract method, all animals would talk
        for word in self.vocabulary: print (word)

class Cat(Animal):
    vocabulary = ["Meow", "Muuuew", "Maow"]

class Dog(Animal):
    vocabulary = ["Woof", "Waf", "Haw"]

animals = [Cat('Missy'),
           Cat('Mr. Mistoffelees'),
           Dog('Lassie')]

for animal in animals:
    print animal.name + ': ' + animal.talk()
```

Prints the following:

```
Missy: Meow Muuuew Maow
Mr. Mistoffelees: Meow Muuuew Maow
Lassie: Woof Waf Haw
```

Clearly, this won't work since vocabulary will be empty, as it is in the base class.
I tried to find a solution using `super`, e.g:

```
class Cat(Animal):
    vocabulary = ["Meow", "Muuuew", "Maow"]
    def talk(self):
        super(Animal,Cat).talk()
```

But the result would be `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'talk'`

Am I using `super` wrong?

Comment: In your example, `vocabulary` is an instance attribute of `Animal` but is a class attribute of `Dog` and `Cat`. Where should it actually live?

Comment: Thank you for your comment,
vocabulary should by a class attribute, not an instance variable.

Comment: Your edit changed the nature of the question too much; I've reverted it. If you want a method that operates on the class instead of the instance, look up [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

Answer (score 0):

Python is dynamically typed. There is no need to somehow declare an "abstract data member" in `Animal` for `Animal` methods to refer to `self.vocabulary`; in fact, your attempts to declare an "abstract data member" are causing your problems.

Just remove `self.vocabulary = []`, and `talk` will automatically find the subclass `vocabulary` when it tries to access `self.vocabulary`.

Comment: Thank you, my question wasnt clear enough, I have edited it so show that my goal is to use instance variables, no any 'self'.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few unresolved issues in your code, but since python is so dynamic, it will find the subclass instance attribute through normal lookup:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def talk(self):
        for word in self.vocabulary: print (word)

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
      super().__init__(name)
      self.vocabulary = ["Meow", "Muuuew", "Maow"]

class Dog(Animal):
  def __init__(self, name):
      super().__init__(name)
      self.vocabulary = ["Woof", "Waf", "Haw"]

animals = [Cat('Missy'),
           Cat('Mr. Mistoffelees'),
           Dog('Lassie')]

for animal in animals:
    print(animal.name, end=': ')
    animal.talk()
```

If you want something to enforce this requirement more explicitly in the code, you can make `Animal` an *abstract base class* and make an abstruct property named `vocabulary`:

```
import abc

class Animal(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def vocabulary(self):
      ...

    def talk(self):
        for word in self.vocabulary: print (word)

class Cat(Animal):
    @property
    def vocabulary(self):
      return ["Meow", "Muuuew", "Maow"]
```

[here is a live link](https://repl.it/@RyanHaining1/abstractproperty-2)

Comment: `abstractproperty` is deprecated. The recommended way is now to do `@property` `@abstractmethod` in that order (which is a pretty annoying API, since you have to memorize the order).

Comment: This is helpfull, but can you apply this for working with class variables?